# Documents folder suddenly not found

Tags: permissions, files, home-directory

When I try to open my Documents folder, a window comes up with:

> Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
>   Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file `/home/mikael/Documents`: No such file or directory

When I right click on it and click on properties it says that type, size, location, accessed, and modified are all unknown.

Under permissions it reads: The permissions of "" could not be determined.

The Documents folder has also for some unknown reason moved outside of my Home folder and is now located "under Computer" in the left field of Files. Although if I hover over it with the mouse it says that it's in /home/mikael/Documents.

I haven't a clue what has happened here. My question is: How do I get my files back? (I have a backup but it would be nice to know what happened!)

Comment: Its difficult to speculate what happened if you dont know it either. Did you try using `ls -la` command in a terminal for the Home and Documents folders?

Comment: Yes, I did try this and it couldn't find the folder. I guess the problem is solved now since I have restored the folder from backup but it is scary anyway.